# Angular View not updating after retrieving data from database

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am currently working on an app that retrieves data on the of change of $routeParams. So here's how it begins:

```
function artistCtrl($scope, $http, $location, dataFactory, $routeParams){
$scope.artistName = $routeParams.artistname

$scope.$watch('artistName', function(newValue, oldValue){
  $scope.artistInfo = dataFactory.getArtist(newValue)
})

$scope.artistInfo = {
  artist_name: dataFactory.artistInfo.artist_name,
  artist_genre: dataFactory.artistInfo.artist_genre,
  artist_imageurl: dataFactory.artistInfo.artist_imageurl,
  artist_bio: dataFactory.artistInfo.artist_bio
};
}
```

The callback for `$watch` here is run. `dataFactory.getArtist` retrieves `newValue` from my database which is being done successfully. That is done like this:

**dataFactory.js**

```
  dataFactory.getArtist = function(artist){   
    return dataFactory.checkDb(artist).then(function(dbData){
      if(dbData.data != "No data"){
          dataFactory.artistInfo = dbData.data[0] 
      } 
      return dbData.data[0]
    })
  }

dataFactory.artistInfo = "";
```

`dataFactory` is a factory I created in another file.

**artistpage.html**

```
<div class="container this">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <div><h1>{{artistInfo.artist_name}}</h1></div>
          <div rate-yo id='stars' rating="myRating" class="col-sm-4"></div>
          <div id='reviews'>23 Reviews</div>
          <div><h2>{{artistInfo.artist_genre}}</h2></div>
          <div><p>{{artistInfo.artist_bio}}</p></div>
          <div><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="somefunc()">Submit a Review</button></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 reviews">
          <div><img class="artistpageimage" src={{artistInfo.artist_imageurl}}></div>
        </div>
      </div>

</div>
```

I don't understand why my view isn't being updated. I am attempting to update $scope.artistName by assigning the returned `dataFactory.getArtist(newValue)`
and also by assigning the new data to `dataFactory.artistInfo` I have read about $apply, but I am having a hard time figuring out how to apply it in this context. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does getArtist return a promise or a value. If it's a promise try something like the below:

```
$scope.$watch('artistName', function(newValue, oldValue){
  dataFactory.getArtist(newValue).then(function(value) {
    $scope.artistInfo = value;
  })
})
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is that `dataFactory.getArtist(newValue)` is returning a promise, which you're assigning directly to `artistInfo`. Try replacing it with:

```
dataFactory.getArtist(newValue).then(function (info) {
    $scope.artistInfo = info;
});
```